# Merge 2 rows into one with 2 columns with pivot

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello I have tried to merge two rows into one column with In and out time for a agency. Here is my query

```
   select
   agency_name,       
   "IN",
   out
   from   (
       select 
        eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.agent_id,

        eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_name,
        eofficeuat.gatepass.agency_name,
        eofficeuat.gatepass.agency_id,
        TO_CHAR(eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.scantime, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH12:MI:SS PM') as Time,            
        eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.action as action,
        eofficeuat.gatelist.shortname as gate,
        eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.passnumber,
        eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.cardnumber,
        eofficeuat.gatepass.vehicletype,
        eofficeuat.gatepass.ISSUEDATETIME,
        row_number() over (
        partition by agency_name, trunc(to_date(TO_CHAR(eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.scantime, 'dd-mm-yyyy HH12:MI:SS PM'), 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm')), action order by eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.scantime) rn
    FROM
        eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle
        INNER JOIN eofficeuat.cnf_agents ON eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.agent_id = eofficeuat.cnf_agents.agent_id
        INNER JOIN eofficeuat.gatelist ON eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.gate_id = eofficeuat.gatelist.id
        INNER JOIN eofficeuat.gatepass ON eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.passnumber = eofficeuat.gatepass.id

    WHERE 

        eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.passnumber = '10000920616'
        and eofficeuat.entrylog_vehicle.scantime between TO_DATE ('03/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') and TO_DATE ('04/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') 


    )
  pivot (max(time) for action in ('IN' as "IN", 'OUT' as "OUT"))
  order by rn;
```

and here is Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d465a/1 
I wanted to merge two rows into one which have in and out for 03-10-2019 date and similarly for 04-10-2019 date. thats why I used analytics function
. but this not merging into one rows. so there showing 4 rows but I wanted 2 rows to show. can you please help me for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much more simply by using a pivot on the table without the case expressions, like so:

```
select agency_name,
       dt,
       "IN",
       out
from   (select agency_name,
               trunc(to_date(time, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm')) dt,
               to_date(time, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') time,
               action,
               row_number() over (partition by agency_name, trunc(to_date(time, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm')), action order by time) rn
        from   kvtest)
pivot (max(time) for action in ('IN' as "IN", 'OUT' as "OUT"))
order by rn;
```

And [here's the SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a6594/12) to support this answer.

This works by finding the day, and then identifying the nth in and out rows in that day. Then we pivot the data, leaving the rn as one of the columns to pivot on, meaning that if there were 3 ins and outs in a day, you'd end up with 3 rows in the output.

If you want the INs and OUTs to work across days (e.g. arrive before midnight, leave after midnight), you're going to need a different solution. I have assumed in my answer that the corresponding OUT to an IN will always be on the same day.

As an aside, why is your `TIME` column defined as VARCHAR2? That's a bad datatype to store date or timestamp information in. I would hope that your actual table is really of `DATE` (or `TIMESTAMP`) datatype. If it isn't, I seriously suggest you look at changing the datatype to a more appropriate one.

---

If you simply want the earliest IN time and the latest OUT time per day, all you need is an conditional aggregate query, e.g.:

```
select agency_name,
       trunc(to_date(time, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm')) dt,
       min(case when action = 'IN' then to_date(time, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end) "IN",
       max(case when action = 'OUT' then to_date(time, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm') end) out
from   kvtest
group by agency_name,
         trunc(to_date(time, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss pm'));
```

And [here's the supporting SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a6594/14).

Comment: can you please give me a solution based on my code. I used the case for agency will have many in and out daily so I used the case to get first in and last out time

Comment: If you want people to help you better, you should make sure your sample data and expected outcome matches your scenario(s), and you should make it clear in your question what the requirement is supposed to be. Your question doesn't make it clear that you're after the first in and last out time for each day.

Comment: yes, you are right, but I wanted to solve at my query, by the way your solution is going to work fine, I am trying with it and will get back to you.

Comment: I have updated the query with the solution you gave at my question. But I am still getting two rows. can you please check

Comment: and let me know please for first and in last out for a date range like 1th October to 5th October like you have done here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a6594/14 . but I wanted daily from 1 - 5th October

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Please ask a new question, and provide sample data that covers all your requirements, along with the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a lot and use `TRUNC` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`:

**Oracle Setup**:

*Don't store dates as strings; use appropriate data types, so in this case, `DATE`:*

```sql
create table kvtest ( agency_name, action, TIME ) AS
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'IN',  DATE '2019-10-03' + INTERVAL '15:52:26' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'OUT', DATE '2019-10-03' + INTERVAL '18:17:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'IN',  DATE '2019-10-04' + INTERVAL '15:52:26' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'OUT', DATE '2019-10-04' + INTERVAL '18:17:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT agency_name,
       "IN",
       OUT
FROM   (
  SELECT T.*,
         TRUNC( TIME ) AS day
  FROM   kvtest t
)
PIVOT ( MIN( time ) FOR action IN ( 'IN' AS "IN", 'OUT' AS "OUT" ) )
ORDER BY day;
```

**Output**:

```
| AGENCY_NAME |                   IN |                  OUT |
|-------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| ABC LIMITED | 2019-10-03T15:52:26Z | 2019-10-03T18:17:48Z |
| ABC LIMITED | 2019-10-04T15:52:26Z | 2019-10-04T18:17:48Z |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/866621/9)

---

**Update**:

> [from comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429964/merge-2-rows-into-one-with-2-columns-with-pivot/58431483?noredirect=1#comment103206365_58430390): agency will have many in and out daily so I used the case to get first in and last out time

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
create table kvtest ( agency_name, action, TIME ) AS
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'IN',  DATE '2019-10-03' + INTERVAL '15:52:26' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'OUT', DATE '2019-10-03' + INTERVAL '18:17:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'IN',  DATE '2019-10-03' + INTERVAL '18:52:26' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'OUT', DATE '2019-10-03' + INTERVAL '19:17:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'IN',  DATE '2019-10-04' + INTERVAL '15:52:26' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'OUT', DATE '2019-10-04' + INTERVAL '18:17:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'IN',  DATE '2019-10-05' + INTERVAL '23:17:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'OUT', DATE '2019-10-06' + INTERVAL '00:17:48' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'IN',  DATE '2019-10-06' + INTERVAL '09:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC LIMITED', 'OUT', DATE '2019-10-06' + INTERVAL '15:00:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT agency_name,
       MIN( CASE action WHEN 'IN'  THEN TIME END ) AS "IN",
       MAX( CASE action WHEN 'OUT' THEN TIME END ) AS OUT
FROM   kvtest 
GROUP BY agency_name, TRUNC( TIME )
ORDER BY agency_name, TRUNC( TIME );
```

**Output**:

```
| AGENCY_NAME |                   IN |                  OUT |
|-------------|----------------------|----------------------|
| ABC LIMITED | 2019-10-03T15:52:26Z | 2019-10-03T19:17:48Z |
| ABC LIMITED | 2019-10-04T15:52:26Z | 2019-10-04T18:17:48Z |
| ABC LIMITED | 2019-10-05T23:17:48Z |               (null) |
| ABC LIMITED | 2019-10-06T09:00:00Z | 2019-10-06T15:00:00Z |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b8d0b/3)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is interleaved as in the question, pivoting seems way more complicated than necessary.  You can just use an analytic function and filtering:

```
select agency_name, time as in_time, out_time
from (select k.*,
             min(case when "action" = 'OUT' then time end) over
                  (partition by agency_name
                   order by time desc
                  ) as out_time
      from kvtest k
     ) k
where "action" = 'IN';
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6fefe/2) is the db<>fiddle.

Comment: If you have an `IN` without an `OUT` then it will return duplicate `OUT` times http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b22d1/1

Comment: @MT0 . . . I think it is unclear what the OP would want in that case.  I'm not so sure `pivot` produces the desired result either.